# How to write update db hook for alter the table(make sure the existing data should not corrupt) in drupal

Tags: hooks

Can anyone please help me to write the update db hook for altering the table. Actually I want change the column size of desc field
something like :

function abc_update_1001(){
 // what will the code 
}

Example : Table name : shared_data

```
--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title        | varchar(29)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| desc         | varchar(2000) | NO   |     |         |       |
| time         | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The alerted table should look like:

```
--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title        | varchar(29)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| desc         | varchar(3000) | NO   |     |         |       |
| time         | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Drupal 7 or 8??

Comment: Hi Jaypan , i use Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function hook_update_n() {
  db_change_field('shared_data', 'desc', 'desc', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 3000,
  ));
}
```

Comment: Add this code to module.install in your module